# Self Organizing Maps in Mathematica (SOMs)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, som

Does anybody know of, or have, a reasonable implementation of SOMs in Mathematica?

Comment: [This might or might not help ...](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://library.wolfram.com%20self%20organizing%20map%20-site:http://library.wolfram.com/search/)

Comment: Thanks, I know about this one.  I'm looking for some free code.  I am pretty sure I can writ it myself, but I would rather improve an existing piece of code if that is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There is a third-party *Mathematica* package called [machine learning framework](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/products/mlf), which implements self-organizing maps.